# How long until a website logs you out when doing browser automation?

Tags: python, cookies, selenium

I am using selenium and python to do browser automation. My program will run constantly but I don't want to get logged out of the website.

How long would it take for a website to log me out while I am idle?
How can I keep it from logging me out? Would refreshing a page on the website be enough? This is not a site like a bank or store where they have security stuff. I just don't want to get logged out.

The website I am working on are points2shop.com or cashle.com.

Comment: Your question does not have one answer since it really depends on the website. Are you interested to know http defaults? Do you know the technology that the website is using (asp.net, php, RoR, another)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session timeout is set on server side - unless you actually try to time it by incrementing inactivity time and see when it times you out, there is no way for you to determine what the timeout period is.

Any HTTP request (that should include page refresh) would most likely cause you to remain logged in though.